# Getting a response from a modal dialog using a promise

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a dialog in order to replace the browser‘s original alert and confirm dialogs since I do not like them. My dialog is very flexible in it‘s use.
So my function is called msgBox and it has got the following syntax:
**msgBox (prompt, title, buttons, modal, gradient)**
All params are optional. In that case the function uses default values.
So far it works excellent already. Please see the code below.
I want to achieve now, getting as result the button that is clicked by the user to assign it to a variable or use it in an If-statement.
For example:

```
let response = msgBox("Load Settings?", "Confirm", ["Yes","No", "Restore defaults"]);
```

or

```
if (msgBox("Load file?", "Confirm", ["Yes","No", "Search"]) == 'Yes') { 
   // do some stuff
}
```

I want the dialog work this way, that it returns'false' in case it is non-modal and the user clicked on an area outside, otherwise it should return the clicked button as string in order to evaluate it.
Here is the code so far:

```
let isModal = true;
let msgBoxAnswer = null;

//  #####################################################################################
//  PURPOSE:        Displays a modal | modeless dialog with dynamical buttons
//  
//  PARAMETER:      - prompt    = prompt text
//                  - titel     = Titelzeie des Dialogs 
//                  - buttons   = Button-Array, sepatated by komma - Default = 'Ok'
//                  - modal     = dialog modal | modeless - default = modal
//                  - gradient  = optional: gradient of the titlebar
//  RETURNS:        : the value of the clicked button as string
//  #####################################################################################
async function asyncMsgBox(prompt, title, buttons = ['Ok'], modal = true, gradient) {
    // do some init stuff...
    msgBoxAnswer = null; 
    if (prompt == null) {prompt = ''}
    if (title == null || title.trim() == '') {
        title = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML;
    }
    isModal = modal;
    let classnames = 'overlay';
    if (modal) { classnames += ' dark'}
    
    // search for the parent container (usually it's the <body>)
    let parent = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    parent.innerHTML += `<div id="msgBoxBG" class="${classnames}" onclick="closeDialog('cancel')"></div>`;

    // catching an empty button-array
    if (buttons[0] == '') {buttons[0] = 'Ok'}

    // first create the buttons! 
    // otherwise the <div> is going to be closed automatically
    let btnCode ='';            
    for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        const btn = buttons[i];
        btnCode += `<button class="btnMsgbox" onclick="closeDialog('${btn}')">${btn}</button>`;
    }

    classnames = 'titlebar';
    if (gradient) { classnames += ' gradient'}

    let container = $('msgBoxBG');
    container.innerHTML = `
        <div class="dialog">
            <div class ="${classnames}">
                <h2 id="msgCaption">${title}</h2>
            </div>
            <p id="msgPrompt">${prompt}</p>
            ${btnCode}
        </div>`;


    try {
    // HERE START THE PROBLEMS...
    let answer = await closeDialog(); 
        return answer; // resolve()
    } catch(err){ 
        return false; // reject()
    }
}

function closeDialog(response){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if (response) { 
            if (isModal && response == 'cancel') {return};
            
            if (!isModal && response == 'cancel') {
                $('msgBoxBG').remove();
                reject('false');
            } else if (response !='cancel') {
                $('msgBoxBG').remove();
                resolve(response);
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is, that await closeDialog() finds the response-parameter 'undefined' at the first call and returns before the user is able to click on any button at all, which should call the same function.

I must add that I am not very experienced in Javascript yet. So if anyone has another suggestion or solution how to solve the problem, I am open to learn.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: For your comment look at jsdocs https://devhints.io/jsdoc